# Which are causes and effects in $D$, $E$, $B$, $H$ fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, dielectric

in my book (I'm not putting the reference here since it's not in english) of electromagnetic fields, the following statement is reported about $\vec{E},\vec{D},\vec{B},\vec{H}$ fields:

> We will assume $\vec{D},\vec{B}$ as the effects generated inside a material by the causes $\vec{E},\vec{H}$. In a linear, homogeneous, isotropic medium, the relationships between causes and effects are $\vec{D} = \epsilon \vec{E}$ and $\vec{B} = \mu \vec{H}$.

The book assumes $\vec{E},\vec{H}$ as the primal causes of electric/magnetic effects inside a medium, and for this reason all the electromagnetic problems are solved in terms of these two quantities, and not in terms of $\vec{D},\vec{B}$.

Well, I don't understand exactly this kind of analysis because:

1. $\vec{D}$ may be thought as a sort of electric field, but which is generated only by free charges, while $\vec{E}$ is the total electric field, generated both by free charges and by polarization charges generated by the medium response to the external electric field. I'd say that this external electric field is $\vec{D}$, since it's generated by free charges that don't belong to the dielectric.

So, I'd say, that $\vec{D}$ is the cause (external), and  $\vec{E}$ is the overall effect, due to the contribution of both $\vec{D}$ and dielectric effect. I don't understand why the book says the opposite.

2. $\vec{H}$ may be thought as the magnetic field generated by conduction currents, without considering the effects of magnetization currents created by the external magnetic field  $\vec{H}$.  $\vec{B}$ is the resulting total magnetic field, due both to conduction and magnetization currents.

So, in this case, I agree with the book that  $\vec{H}$ is the cause and  $\vec{B}$ the effect.

But how we can explain 1)?

Comment: Well, vacuum is treated in terms of E and B, so I've always thought that D and H are relevant for electromagnetic fields in matter.